# Get error string from Jericho SourceFormatter

Tags: jericho-html-parser

I'm using jericho's SourceFormatter to do indentation of HTML.
Right now if there is an issue in my HTML formatter sends it to server console.

How can I catch error and output it into my log system (actually I want to get it as a String/Object)?

Here is example of code I use

```
private String indent(String html) {
    SourceFormatter formatter = new SourceFormatter(new Source(html));
    formatter.setIndentString("\t");
    formatter.setTidyTags(false);
    formatter.setCollapseWhiteSpace(true);

    return formatter.toString(); // if HTML have issues, they go to server's consol
}
```

[LoggerProvider](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/LoggerProvider.html) - represent loggin system of hericho

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is possible to realize Logger interface and use it as your own logger.

```
class LoggerCustom implements net.htmlparser.jericho.Logger {
    ...
}
```

And than pass it's object to Source object.

```
Source source = new Source(html);
LoggerCustom logger = new LoggerCustom();
source.setLogger(logger); // here I pass my Logger object.

SourceFormatter formatter = new SourceFormatter(source);

formatter.setIndentString("\t");
formatter.setTidyTags(false);
formatter.setCollapseWhiteSpace(true);

String result = formatter.toString();
```

Comment: Under the hood Jericho uses slf4j and Logback (see the last line of https://sourceforge.net/projects/jerichohtml/files/jericho-html/3.4/) so if you're using a logging framework you can capture the output that way,